# RTSP stream to URL on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-live-api

I'm trying to create a streamer in my app over `RTSP` protocol to use it for Facebook live. I got this [Project](https://github.com/OpenWatch/H264-RTSP-Server-iOS) and it seems to work perfect except one thing which is the URL. The library get the device IP via this code :

```
+ (NSString*) getIPAddress
{
    NSString* address;
    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = nil;

    // get all our interfaces and find the one that corresponds to wifi
    if (!getifaddrs(&interfaces))
    {
        for (struct ifaddrs* addr = interfaces; addr != NULL; addr = addr->ifa_next)
        {
            if (([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:addr->ifa_name] isEqualToString:@"en0"]) &&
                (addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET))
            {
                struct sockaddr_in* sa = (struct sockaddr_in*) addr->ifa_addr;
                address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(sa->sin_addr)];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    freeifaddrs(interfaces);
    return address;
}
```

So the stream can be accessed via the IP. **My question is: is there anyway to make the RTSP to stream to a URL so I can provide it to the server?**

Comment: Facebook Live uses RTMP, not RTSP.  You would need to embed an RTMP client of some sort.  In any case, what you're doing likely violates Facebook's policies.  https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#liveAPI

Comment: @Brad WoW I'm in a big trouble !!! Thank you so much for your interest.